# How to know if AD Group is member of other AD Group. (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

I am trying to get a similar result as in IsInRole as in this example:

```
Dim MyPrincipal As New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(New System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(TextBox2.Text))
If MyPrincipal.IsInRole("DOMAIN\GroupName")
    Then MsgBox("User is Member of AD Group")
End If
```

But I need to do it for groups, in that case, MyPrincipal.IsInRole wouldn't work (I think that only applies for User Accounts) and had never try it for groups before, so not even an idea where to start.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Already found the answer, If any interested, can be achieved by using the GroupPrincipal Class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

```
    **

Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, "fabrikam.com", "DC=fabrikam,DC=com", "administrator", "SecretPwd123")
        Dim grp As GroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Administrators")
        If grp IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each p As Principal In grp.GetMembers(False)
                If TypeOf p Is GroupPrincipal Then
                    Console.WriteLine(p.Name)
                End If
            Next
            grp.Dispose()
        End If
        ctx.Dispose()
```

**

Many thanks to Paul on this!